# Java reuse scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to extract string from txt file with matching data with the problem below

when I'm trying to reuse my scanner it consume all the resources and got stuck in the page

```
String tmpStr1 = scanStr("Name :",streamData);
String tmpStr2 = scanStr("Email :",streamData); //it got stuck on this line

public String scanStr(String Str, String fileData){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(fileData);
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        try{
            s.findInLine(Str+" (\\S*)(.*)");
            if(s.match()!=null) { 
                MatchResult result = s.match();
                s.close();
                return result.group(1);
            }
            s.nextLine();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){

        }
    }
    s.close();
    return "";
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: First of all, close statement should be inside "finally". How are you stuck?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do (ignoring the implementation for the moment)?

Comment: I got stuck while trying to convert the file I upload, it worked fine during the first scan, but when I add the second statement it got stuck(unable to proceed to the next page)

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Extract name and email? Because if so, a scanner isn't the best approach.

Comment: My project work as below
A jsp page for uploading file > extract data from the txt file(which is the code above) > change field value of form based on the extracted data(I'm able to change the name with single statement, not able to while trying to reuse the scanner again)

Comment: Trying to reuse what scanner? Do you mean trying to call your `scanStr()` *method* a second time? That's not 'reuse'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to advance to the next line if no match, with `nextLine().` Otherwise the Scanner's position is unchanged and you will scan the same line forever.
2. `Scanner.match()` doesn't return `null` if there is no match. It throws `IllegalStateException.` See the Javadoc. Ergo testing it for `null` is pointless. What you should be testing is whether `findInLine()` returned `null.` Then you can get rid of the `catch (IllegalStateException ...)` block.
3. Returning `""` is almost always a bad idea, and this is no exception. You should return `null,` indicating no match. `""` would indicate an *empty* name or e-mail address. You need to be able to distinguish the two.

Revised, also using better variable names:

```
public static String scanStr(String prefix, String data)
{
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(data))
    {
        while (s.hasNextLine())
        {
            if (s.findInLine(prefix + " (\\S*)(.*)") != null)
            {
                return s.match().group(1);
            }
            s.nextLine();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

There is no Scanner re-use here, nor should there be.

Comment: I noticed that mistakes and placed s.nextLine() inside the end of the loop but it seems the problem is still there